# What's the best way to implement a Registration REST API for iPhone/Android?

Tags: django, api, rest, registration

I'm writing a backend application with REST API for iPhone and Android. It's an internal API.

At this point, I'm trying to implement a user registration API such that the user can register from the mobile app.

I'm writing using Django and with Django they comes with Cross Site Request Forgery for the web request. I have to disable it for REST API, using django-piston.

So how can I protect my registration API from spamming? throttle? captcha? what's the best practice to implement a registration API? what's the pitfall?

One suggestion came up was to load a webview on the mobile app and have a mobile web registration form such that CSRF can be implemented. It's a solution but not a neat one as I have to create design page for each mobile device or a generic one that might not be suited across all devices.

Many help are appreciated.

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree in that using an OpenID provider is a great way to achieve that. You should look into http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-social-auth or similar projects. An added benefit is that you do not need to save password credentials in your database. Less data to manage, less data to loose.

If you definitely need a classic username/password based scheme and accompanying registration (maybe alongside OpenID based stuff like SO itself), I'd go with the throttling that piston provides. Personally I use captchas only as a last resort, and doing so via a REST interface is probably quite annoying. Do you request a captcha before the registration phase can continue? How do you note that this user has completed the captcha (session+cookies, ...)? You cannot use reCAPTCHA or similar services without using a webview (which would render the whole REST approach obsolete IMO).

I would revisit using a WebView. If you keep your interface clean and simple it shouldn't jar with any conventions on any smartphone platform.

Comment: just curious, what's the reason why captcha can't be use on the REST API level?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you'd have to get the captcha image through REST, display it to the user and then get the answer back in the next call. I find its something an API is not ideal for, as you need a session. I dislike having to keep state between API calls. Maybe its just me though.

Comment: Agreed with stateless API calls (which is one of the fundamental principles of REST!).  However, if you were rolling your own capcha theres no reason why you wouldn't be able to return a "token" (e.g. an MD5 salted hash of the answer) alongside the capcha image URI. Then get your mobile app to verify with the API by sending the users answer along with the original hash they were issued.

Comment: @Jamie Chapman your approach is right, but the captcha id should not be a hash of the solution (then solving the captcha would be solving the hash instead of processing an image). Not saying it wouldn't be safe, but I prefer using a concatenation of a micro timestamp and a random integer (microstamp@randint) to generate a unique resource id or "token" for each created captcha (this approach also allows me to easily eliminate stale captchas).

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to worry about CSRF for your REST API, check this [section](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) in the docs that explains why.

Best way to prevent spam is to collect user data from a verified source, such as an OpenID provider, Facebook, etc. If you want to do this manually, then the simplest way to do it is to take [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) and extend one of the backends. You can take the provided simple backend and use a custom form with a captcha field. This should be enough to weed-out automated registrations. Should be simple enough to get it hooked up with [piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home).

**EDIT:**

You're right, I just re-read the question and noticed I completely disregarded the fact that you already mentioned you're developing your REST API against remote Android/iPhone users. So your API is publicly exposed and accepts requests that aren't originating from your domain or from a browser client for that matter.

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel in your case then, you should implement [Open API Authentication](http://www.slideshare.net/leahculver/oauth-open-api-authentication), since it applies perfectly to your requirements: knowing that you're exchanging information with an actual user, without worrying where the request originated from.

Comment: kRON: i think the CSRF only applies to the AJAX right? For REST API, we have to specifically use csrf_exempt(). At least, that's what I found out when I tried to POST using the REST API provided by django-piston.

Comment: The question is about registering a *new* user...  So the register endpoint can't be secured... which is why he is worried it may be abused